# HTML integrate tabindex with label click

Tags: html

I want to **focus** my element on `label` click like we can do for normal `inputs`

```
<label for="my">label</label>
<div id="my" tabindex="0">focusable</div>
```

`DIV` before focus

[image: Unfocused DIV]

`DIV` after clicking on `element`

[image: Focused DIV]

But this does not work if I click the `label`

Comment: Hi, I am sorry but I don't understand what you are trying to do. You focus elements with the [`focus`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#dom-focus) method available on all and every HTML element. Can't you use that? What does this have to do with tab indexes, mutation observers etc? Put yourself in a position of someone who has no idea what kind of application you are designing and just reads your question. Will they understand what is really being asked for here?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I will try to reformulate the question. Just to clarify before the edit I am just trying to focus `element` on label click, like we can do for the `inputs`

Comment: You cannot label elements that aren't form controls. Meaning your label element labelling the following `div` is invalid. Your (or others') user agent will not complain, probably but if you're designing your own interactive [input] elements, are you sure you want to do away with the `input` element? It gives you everything for free.

Comment: Again thanks for the reply. I am trying to make my custom dropdown and I wanted to make it focusable via label like we can do with `<select>`